# Using Timeshift and Flatpak causes space issues on SSD. How to intelligently take system state backup including Flatpak app?

Tags: linux-mint, backup, ssd, flatpak, ubuntu-mate

Flatpak applications take up a lot of space. Is it wise to take a system backup with Timeshift? What is the solution?